# All the values inside Struct to columns in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery, i have a column 'device' which has nested struct properties looks like this

### device

| brand_name | brand_id | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| huawei | 34j0 | china |

| brand_name | brand_id | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sony | ds5g | japan |

we can convert those device properties to column by doing this
`

```
SELECT
device.brandname 
device.brand_id 
device.country 
from table
```

( the structre of the data is STRUCT<brand_name STRING,brand_id STRING,country STRING>)

but the problem is we can not access every individual elements in device ( like device.brandname
device.brand_id....etc)  if properties have n number of keys, is there a way to loop all the keys in device column in one go, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to loop all the keys in device column in one go

Use below approach

```
select * except(device), device.*
from your_table
```

in case if `device` is the only column in your table  - use below

```
select device.*
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a schema with "device" being a nested structure, something like... (the parent fields are just by way of example)

```
Schema: parent_schema
|- parent_schema_id: string
|- device_owner: string
|- ... other properties ...
+- device: record
|  |- brand_id: string
|  |- brand_name: string
|  |- country: string
:
```

Based on that assumption, you should be able to write a query like...

```
SELECT
    parent_schema_ia,
    device_owner,
    device.brand_id,
    device.brand_name,
    device.country
  FROM parent_schema;
```

You can also reference the `device` columns in `WHERE` clauses like...

```
SELECT
    parent_schema_ia,
    device_owner,
    device.brand_id,
    device.brand_name,
    device.country
  FROM parent_schema
 WHERE device.brand_name = 'huawei';
```

This is all presented nicely on the Google BigQuery help...

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated

**Apologies, if my assumption is incorrect... I wasn't clear from your question what the wider structure looks like.**

Comment: Hi, my problem is that we can access the device properties by device.brand_name...etc , in this test case device has only three properties ( brand_name,brand_id, country) ,but what if the properties have n number of values , i just want to make column for every value , thank you

Comment: it's probably me, but i'm not understanding clearly what your problem is.  happy to help, but maybe try expanding your problem description.  give more context by providing both greater detail around the table structure, some sample data, the expected output, your actual SQL and what your current output looks like.